# Why comparing empty values is not working?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries.

```
students = [{"id":''},{"id":1},{"id":3}]
```

I am iterating through this and looking for dictionaries where id is not `''`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
 for student in students:
     if(student['id'] is not None or student['id'] != ''):
         print("found student" + str(student['id']))
         break
```

But no matter what, it always goes inside the `if` block. Any pointers what is wrong in comparing blank values?

Comment: Shouldn't that be an "and"?

Comment: Aah!! that was very silly of me :) I removed the the 1st condition `if(student['id'] != '')` this was sufficient ! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
if student['id'] not in (None, ''):
    # do someting
```

Answer (score 3):

```
student['id'] is not None or student['id'] != ''
```

- If the value is actually `None`, the second condition will be true, as `None` is not equal to `''`.
- If the value is empty, then the first condition will be true, as empty is not `None`.

As the `or` operator requires at least one of the expressions to be Truthy, this entire expression will be True always. That is why, the control enters the `if` block always.

---

You can use [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), here.

```
"not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"

also,

"not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)".
```

You want, the id to be "not None" and "not empty", so you could have written the same as,

```
if student['id'] is not None and student['id'] != '':
    # print details
```

or

```
if not (student['id'] is None or student['id'] == ''):
    # print details
```

---

Instead, I would recommend writing the same idiomatically, like this

```
for student in students:
    if student['id']:
        # print details
```

Now, if the value is either `None` or empty, the `if` statement will skip the current object. It will print the details only if the `id` is a Truthy value.

---

You can even check if the `id` is present in the dictionary before getting the value, like this

```
for student in students:
    if 'id' in student and student['id']:
        # print details
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(person is not theif or person is not king):
    kings and theif are both allowed into the closure.
    as kings are not thief and thief are not king.
```

The `or` operation only needs `one true condition` to be satisfied. A thing only has one type.

```
 One type will always not be at least one two different things.
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.